# How long did it take to travel from Emond's Field to Baerlon?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, eye-of-the-world

I'm listening to *Eye of the World*(first time reader), and there's a part where Moiraine was explaining to Nynaeve about touching the One Power for the first time, and the reactions to it. She says that the first time you touch the Power is probably something you needed, like a branch reaching out or healing someone, but about 7-10 days later you experience the reaction of touching the Power(fevers, headaches).

This lead me to think about the groups run to Taren Ferry. It's said Rand felt a tingling, and he was urging Bella to run, to keep up with the other faster horses. Then when the group got to Baerlon, he was afflicted with headaches. So, the question is, how long was the run from Emond's Field to Baerlon? Was this meant to be an indication that Rand could touch the One Power himself?

Comment: Related: [What is the time period for The Eye of the World](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/what-is-the-time-period-for-the-eye-of-the-world)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### About a week.

From [this excellent timeline resource](http://www.stevenac.net/wot/tl0998.htm):

> Mar-24: Rand, Mat and Perrin leave Emond's Field with Moiraine, Lan, Egwene and Thom. Rand sees a Draghkar in the sky. They journey along the North Road to Taren Ferry, where Moiraine raises a fog to fool the pursuing Draghkar. [Rand unknowingly channels to restore Bela's strength.] They cross the Taren, after which Moiraine destroys the ferry. They make camp near the river. Moiraine guides Egwene through her first use of the Power.
>
> [...]
>
> Mar-30: They arrive at Baerlon in the evening. They hear of Whitecloaks in Baerlon, trouble in Saldaea, and a battle in Ghealdan. Thom tells Rand some of the Prophecies of the Dragon. Rand dreams, and has his first encounter with Ba'alzamon.

Let's check how we can work this out from the text in the book itself.

- When they leave Emond's Field, it's just after full moon:

  > The moon, only a thin slice less than full, appeared almost close enough to touch, if he stretched, and. . . .
  >
  > <sub>-- *The Eye of the World*, Chapter 10: *Leavetaking*</sub>

  Yes, just after rather than just before, as it was full moon on Winternight:

  > The full moon and drifting clouds made dappled shadows chase one another across the farmyard.
  >
  > <sub>-- *The Eye of the World*, Chapter 5: *Winternight*</sub>
- When they leave Baerlon, the moon is in its last quarter, but still bright enough to cast shadows, so not far past half-moon:

  > The streets of Baerlon were abandoned at that hour of the night; only a few faint glimmers here and there escaped tightly closed shutters, and the light of the moon in its last quarter waxed and waned with the wind-driven clouds [...] Shifting moon shadows recalled the shadows at the end of the hall, the way they had seemed to reach out to the Fade.
  >
  > <sub>-- *The Eye of the World*, Chapter 17: *Watchers and Hunters*</sub>

Comment: I had a feeling you'd be the one to answer, lol. So, then, was that whole thing _meant_ to be an indication to the reader that Rand could channel, or was it just something that he wrote without realizing the implication?

Comment: Also, there is a quote from the book: "There was little in the way of conversation while they lathered and sluiced away a week of
grime with dippers of steaming water." . They just entered Stag and Lion. It can be a proof that they did not have a bath for a week since their escape. Should it be added to an answer, or posted as a separate answer?

Comment: @Schullz Good find, but "a week of grime" could easily mean 5 days' worth, or 10 days' worth; it's not very precise. If you post it as an answer, though, I'll upvote.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Almost certainly yes, it was intended. Too much of a coincidence for the author not to have realised the implication, and Jordan is an absolute master of including hints and foreshadowings ahead of time. It's also mentioned ("[reaction to channelling seven days ago]") on the timeline I linked to, so other people than you have noticed this.

Comment: Moraine directly mentions rands use of the power on bela i believe in the great hunt

Comment: @Himarm Yes, but much later. Are his headaches in Baerlon ever explicitly connected to that in the text?

Comment: @Randal'Thor the headaches, his cockyness towards the white cloaks, and his fever chills , are all mentioned as symptoms of useing the power the first time not to rand but to nyneve and egwene while rands listening, and then we later find out for sure rand first channels during the ride to bearlon so its up to us to connect the dots

Comment: Perrin also had a headache and sickness in Baerlon

Comment: This is also from the book: "The journey to Baerlon took almost a week. " That's in chapter 13, right after they spend the night after crossing the Taren.

Comment: FYI: A week is equal to 10 days in the WOT. https://wot.fandom.com/wiki/Measurement